# What are the possible subspaces of $V$ when $dim(V)=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we say $V$ is $dim = 1$, can we say the only possible subspace is $sp\{0\}$?

Comment: No, because another subspace is $V$ itself.

Comment: $V$ is also a subspace of $V$.